# PHP Sistema pra curar usuário de x em x minutos

Tags: php, mysql

Bom dia pessoal! Estou criando um joguinho de rpg e não estou descobrindo como fazer com que o ele cure o usuário de x em x minutos. Consegui fazer via ajax, mas não é seguro né? Facilmente o usuário pode burlar e curar toda a vida dele se ele quiser... Tem alguma forma de fazer isso sem ajax? No banco de dados já tenho todos os valores, vida, vida máxima etc... Me deem uma força! Valeu.

@EDIT com ajax embora até tenha dado certo, o usuário precisava estar logado pra funcionar, seria algo também que ele não precisasse logar... que o sistema funcionasse mesmo com ele desligado.

Comment: Pesquise sobre Cron, ou algo do tipo, os servidores geralmente disponibilizam "cronômetros" para realizar tarefas agendadas, você pode deixar um arquivo de php já feito para "curar" os players, e utilizar as tarefas agendadas para rodar esse arquivo. Só não tenho certeza o tempo mínimo que eles rodam..

Comment: Humm acho que já vi algo a respeito no meu host... Vou dar uma pesquisada.

@EDIT encontrei, meu host tem a opção tarefas cron avançadas, onde ele pode executar o arquivo php a cada 60 segundos, que é o tempo minimo. Obrigado pela ajuda, vou deixar a pergunta aberta por um tempo pra ver se dão algumas outras idéias! :)

Comment: Que bom que achou, é que eu já tive que fazer isso para um jogo de RPG que tinha criado. Na época essa foi a melhor solução que achei. Qualquer dúvida pode falar

Comment: Só para entender... vc vai enviar alguma coisa para php ou só vai rodar um arquivo que já está lá?

Comment: No momento estou utilizando o cron... Ele roda o php com o script que cura se a vida estiver abaixo do limite máximo...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode ter um evento no banco de dados que a cada x e x tempo faça alguma ação para você, por exemplo:

Tabela personagem, com id, nome e vida.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS personagem (
    id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
    nome VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
    vida INT NOT NULL DEFAULT 50
)
```

Evento, a cada 2 minutos acrescenta +10 a vida do personagem, se a mesma for melhor que 100 (tem de ter controle para se caso a vida estiver em 92, nao ir pra 102, pois no exemplo a vida maxima é 100, mad não vou fazer isso)

```
DELIMITER $$
--
-- Eventos
--
CREATE EVENT `realizaCura` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 2 MINUTE
STARTS '2016-05-12 15:11:10' ON COMPLETION NOT PRESERVE ENABLE 
DO UPDATE personagem SET personagem.vida = (personagem.vida + 10) WHERE personagem.vida < 100$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Desculpem se tiver erro de sintaxe, fiz pelo telefone.

Comment: Quanto ao fato de não ser seguro utilizando ajax, certo, ele poderia manipular, todavia poderia também trabalhar em uma "chave" e ou bloqueio que permita que tal ajax só possa ser rodado a cada X tempo e se a chave não for a válida ele não executa. Outra alternativa seria a utilização de CRON como já dito pelo Fleuquer Lima.

Como é feito quando ele "perde" vida? Se for feito através de ajax, você deve levar em consideração que isso também pode ser manipulável...

Comment: Bacana Ivcs, +1